# Parsing a SQL spatial column in Python

Tags: sql, python-2.7

I am struggling a bit as I am new to programming. I am currently writing a python script and I am a bit stuck. The goal is to parse some spatial information the gets pulled from SQL to a format that is usable for my py script down the line.

I was able to CAST through a SQL query and fetchall using the obdc module. However once I fetch the data that is where it gets trick for me. Here is an example of a print from the fetchall:

```
[(u'POLYGON ((7014.186279296875 6602.99658203125 1612.5, 7015.984375 6600.416015625 1612.5))',), (u'POLYGON ((6730.962646484375 6715.2490234375 1522.5, 6730.0869140625 6714.13916015625 1522.5))',)]
```

I am not exactly sure what I am getting here it is like a list of tuples. which I have tried converting to a list of list, but there must be something I am missing.

Here is the usable format I am looking for:

```
[[7014.186279296875, 6602.99658203125, 1612.5], [7015.984375, 6600.416015625, 1612.5]]

[[6730.962646484375, 6715.2490234375, 1522.5], [6730.0869140625, 6714.13916015625, 1522.5]]
```

Any ideas of how I can accomplish this? Maybe there is a better way to CAST in SQL or a module in python that would be easier to use instead of just doing a `cursor.fetchall()` and parsing? Or any any parsing help would be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do parsing, that should be straight forward. For example you've provided next code would do the thing:

```
result = []
for element in data:
    single_elements = element[0][10:-2].split(', ')
    for se in single_elements:
        row = str(se).split(' ')
        result.append([float(a) for a in row])
```

Result will contain what you need. If parsing is not an option, then paste some of your code so I can see how you're fetching data.

Comment: Thanks @PerunSS. Your code works well except the strings in the list need to be floated and the unicode removed. The code up to that point is not so complex. I use import odbc, and the query = "SELECT TOP 2 CAST ([ggem_value] AS varchar(max)) FROM [Atlas_STP].[dbo].[geom_geometry_sqlgeometry]" , then do a fetch all.

Comment: @erok54 Added conversion to string and to float later. As for improve while fetching data, I assume you're using T-SQL, and I'm not that good with T-SQL, but if you can past data sample from database, maybe I can work out something.